# Cursor with JOIN and WHERE MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a repetition in 'cursor' that uses 'join', but it doesn't work.

Already tested without 'join' and works normally.

My code:

```
    DECLARE hvDataAtual DATE;
    DECLARE manDataAtual DATETIME;
    DECLARE motCodAtual INT;

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE Crs_vei_man 
        CURSOR FOR (
        SELECT hvedatageracao, hvedatageracao, hvemotorista 
         FROM tableone INNER JOIN tabletwo ON hveveiculo = manveiculo 
         WHERE SUBSTRING(mandata, 1, 10) = SUBSTRING(hvedatageracao, 1, 10) LIMIT 10);


    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN Crs_vei_man;
        myloop: LOOP
                FETCH Crs_vei_man
                INTO hvDataAtual,
                  manDataAtual,
                  motCodAtual;

                -- Insert 1 row (null, null, null) ?
                INSERT INTO testes VALUES(hvDataAtual, manDataAtual, motCodAtual);

                IF done THEN
                 LEAVE myloop;
                END IF;

                IF motCodAtual > 0 THEN
                 INSERT INTO testes VALUES('hvDataAtual', 'manDataAtual', 'motCodAtual');
                END IF;            

        END LOOP;
    CLOSE Crs_vei_man;
```

This code is in a stored procedure.
What is happening?

Comment: Why are you using a cursor for this, rather than set-based operations?

Comment: You havent' shown the non-join version, or defined what constitutes "works normally"; and as Gordon implied, this looks like it could be accomplished with a relatively simple `INSERT... SELECT`. Although this `INSERT INTO testes VALUES('hvDataAtual', 'manDataAtual', 'motCodAtual');` doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The code of my question (as well as the insert) is just demonstrating the problem of "FETCH". What I am going to develop is something more complex and for that I need the query data with join at the cursor. The non-association version is this: `DECLARE Crs_vei_man CURSOR FOR (SELECT hvedatageracao, hvedatageracao, hvemotorista FROM tableone LIMIT 10);`

Comment: I think the problem may be with SUBSTRING because I tested this query and it worked with two results less than the limit: `SELECT hvedatageracao, mandata, hvemotorista FROM historico_veiculo INNER JOIN manutencao ON hveveiculo = manveiculo ORDER BY hvedatageracao DESC LIMIT 100`, In any case I will not use LIMIT, I just want to solve the problem of WHERE with JOIN.

Comment: I'm not sure what you thought the problem with FETCH was, but you should really be checking for "done" and exiting the loop when done **before** trying to use the values from the FETCH, done means you did not get more data.